# Why spread syntax muting the objects inside the array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

as you know guys there is multiple way to copy an array without copy it reference , i noticed that

if you have the following array :

```
const x = [{age:25},{age:15}];
```

and you need to copy that array using spread syntax like so

```
const z = [...x];
```

after update the z array it will update the organ array

```
z[0].age = 50
```

but if you copy the array using Json parser like so

```
const z = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x));
```

you will not face this issue , any clue why this happening .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: The objects from the original array are copied by reference. Using the JSON parser basically performs a deep copy, so you have all new objects.

Comment: `[...x]` made a ***shallow*** copy of x. In your case `x` is an array of object references. Those references are copied to the new array, but the objects are not duplicated.

Answer (score 2):

`{age:25}` is an object. When you copy the contents of an array in the first case, you clone the array, but the array contains references to objects; the cloned array then contains the same references. Thus, when you change an object in the first one, you've also changed the object in the second one - since they're the same object, not merely a lookalike.

As an analogy: Jack and Meg belong to a DnD club. Then an anime club forms, and everyone from the DnD club also joins the anime club. If everyone in the anime club gets an anime club membership card, do people in DnD club (Jack and Meg) have an anime membership card? Why?

When you go through JSON, you make new objects that look like the original ones, but are not the same objects. Jack and Meg join the DnD club. Anime club opens, and their respective identical twins Joe and Peg join the anime club. If Joe and Peg get an anime club membership card, Jack and Meg won't have one.

Answer (score 1):

You are mutating the object inside the array, which still has the same reference.
The array spread will only do a shallow copy, it will still use the same reference for the object in it.

You can use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the array and return a new copy of the object (a shallow copy) using the [object spread syntax which is a proposal in stage 3](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) :

```
const z = x.map(o => ({...o}));
```

Running example:

```js
const x = [{age:25},{age:15}];
const z = x.map(o => ({...o}));
z[0].age = 50

console.log(x);
```

Comment: This is still a shallow copy, just 2 levels deep instead of 1.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a weird issue, this is simply how objects work.

`JSON.stringify(x)` creates a copy of the object in string format, which completely disconnects the reference to the original object(**x**), and then the *string* is rehydrated into an object using `JSON.parse`

By using `[...x]` you are simply storing a reference to the object and its properties within another data structure. That is why, though they appear to be altering something different because they are different variables, they are nothing more than a reference to the same location in memory. Any change is made to the data in that location, not the variable. They share the same data pool so to speak.